# PYQT Display stops displaying changes periodically, fixes when changing element

Tags: python, windows, pyqt5

I am having a small issue with PYQT that I cannot seem to find an answer for. I have made several apps using PYQT that do a multitude of functions but they all seem to have this one similar issue. When I leave my machine (windows 10) idle for a bit (not moving mouse/keyboard), the display will appear to 'freeze' but it is not actual frozen, just the display. The way to fix this is to change ANY element (increase spinbox value, minimize/maximize screen, etc).

This is particularly a problem with a video app I am working on where a camera is displaying video and suddenly it looks like the app is frozen until I 'fix' it. I am not sure if its a PYQT thing or perhaps windows itself. I will post relevant code below:

I can post more as needed but this is how I start my app:

```
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Ui()
    widget = QtWidgets.QStackedWidget()
    widget.addWidget(window)
    widget.showMaximized()
    app.exec_()
    window.stop_threads()
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: How is that "the relevant code"? that is basically every Qt application..
And it is probably windows thing, Try looking for  a [power plan](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/21434-choose-power-plan-windows-10-a.html) or something related.

Comment: The reason I posted that code was because I was thinking that it could be related to how I create the window. As for the power plan, I have everything set to never turn off display, sleep, etc.

Comment: If this helps, the area where everything gets really messy is when I change push button colors frequently. I have a grid of push buttons (256) and I let a user select points for a start and end point. Once it starts, the pushbutton on the start will be red and you will be able to follow the red square as it goes to the end point. This means every step, I am coloring two push buttons. What happens is, after so many color changes, some will not change and when I minimize/maximize the screen, it all fixes it self.

Comment: You might try `app.processEvents()` near the code that changes the colors of the buttons.

Comment: Is there a way to access the app (QApplication) from anywhere in the app, basically a global app variable? I could pass the app down to everywhere it needs it but its several layers into my code where the button color changes, wondering if there is a cleaner way.